# How to obtain public certificate from Azure Active Directory

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, certificate, asp.net-core-webapi

Our .net core based web api needs to validate the the JWT access tokens received from third party but trusted AAD. In order to do that token signature validation our web api needs to have public certificate of trusted AAD. This functionality is in POC phase. So how to get/download public certificate (.cer file) of AAD?

Comment: Any help to download public certificate (.cer file) of AAD would be appreciated. It (.cer file) is required in token consuming application to do token signature verification.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use the standard JWT Bearer authentication scheme which handles this aspect for you.
You specify the `Authority` and `ClientId` to it and it'll handle the rest.

But if you are curious about the details,
I can explain a bit.
First you take your authority, e.g. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/company.com/v2.0` (or `https://login.microsoftonline.com/company.com` if you are using v1 tokens).
We add `/.well-known/openid-configuration` to the authority to get the metadata URL: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/company.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`.

That metadata URL gives us JSON which includes the `jwks_uri` property.
E.g.:

```
"jwks_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id-here/discovery/v2.0/keys"
```

When we navigate to this URL, we get the public signing keys for Azure AD.

This is all handled under the covers by the JWT Bearer authentication handler though, so you should not implement it yourself.

Comment: Please confirm my below understanding, 1.make request to this metadata url https://login.microsoftonline.com/thirdPartyTestAAD.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration 2. Then again make request to the url mentioned against  "jwks_uri" i.e., "https://login.microsoftonline.com/208xxx3d-b8c0-47yy-943c-7225m15b7b4g/discovery/v2.0/keys". While I am doing this, it returns 3 set of keys which one has to be considered as public key cert. in my app to verify the JWT signed & issued by "thirdPartyTestAAD.onmicrosoft.com" AAD?

Comment: Yup, that's how the public signing keys for tokens are acquired.

Comment: it returns 3 set of keys, which one out of three keys to be considered? Any?

Comment: The token header has the key id that was used. Multiple key pairs are available to allow for rotation.

Comment: But my requirement is bit different, our app requires .cer file to be imported to do third party AAD access token verification. How to get .cer file of a test third party AAD?

Comment: @junnas, let me know for more details of the requirement otherwise some response from you, would be helpful

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with cer files to say if you can build that from the JSON data. But I would guess you can build that file somehow from that.. Since the public key parameters are there.

Comment: "jwks_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant123/discovery/v2.0/keys" & "jwks_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/345tenant67/discovery/v2.0/keys", if you note those "jwks_uri" are for different tentant/customer but they are returning same set of public keys. Is that okay? what is rationale behind it, because they are public keys it can be same across tentant/customer?

Comment: I think usually the keys are the same.. At least I haven't yet ran into a case where they were different. What the digital signature proves to you is that Azure AD signed the token and that it has not been modified. Then you can check the issuer to check which tenant it was.

Comment: @junnas, like you have mentioned in the right above comment, "the keys are the same".Can I cache these public keys in the application in-memory? to avoid n/w latency (or) caching approach not advisable for some reasons?

Comment: You can cache them for some time. In fact the .NET authentication libraries cache them for maybe 8-12 hours and then automatically refresh in the background. The keys *can* change, and have changed in the past. Hard-coding the keys in your app would be a bad idea. But a caching strategy is fine. I think even 24 hours caching would be fine.

Comment: @junnas,do you know how details available in "jwks_uri":"login.microsoftonline.com/345tenant67/discovery/v2.0/keys" are obtained from public certificate? I mean the values for kty, use, kid, x5t, x5c etc.. Is there any .net library available? which takes public cert. as input & spit out those OIDC properties?

Comment: Well, you can use this one to do that and validate the whole token https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/

Comment: @junnas, Not sure above the above link is the answer for my query. My requirement is  how to get details like kty, use, kid, x5t, x5c,issuer etc. from public certificate? Is public enough to get  kty, use, kid, x5t, x5c,issuer etc. or private certificate also required?

Comment: @junnas, some response for my above query would be appreciate

Comment: You don't need private certificate to construct public certificate. I'm not sure how to construct a cer file from those though.

Comment: Does someone know, how to create jwks from public certificate using c#?